# What to do with stair riser metal strap

Tags: carpentry

I’m replacing carpet on stairs with wood.  I ran into this metal strap on one of the risers.  The end of the strap appears to be attached to the outer wall.  Can I just remove it and place my new riser on top of old riser?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you put the riser overtop of the strap.  The thickness must be minimal.

Comment: Not sure if the right side would stick out more.  I’ll notch the back if it does.

Answer (score 7):

Notching the back of the riser would be preferred and won't take much work at all.

Unless you know why/what the strap is there for I would advise against removing it.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I was planning on doing.  Just curious what the strap was for.  Thanks.

Comment: @JC Hard for us to tell.

Comment: @JC can you see anything from under the stairs?  Strap looks like an afterthought, because its not straight.  I'd suspect it was squeaking and some extra nails/screws weren't enough to stop it.

Comment: Can’t look underneath as its all boxed in.  Interesting point on the strap used for squeaking. Thanks.